# How to fix Firefox menubar items unselectable or invisible

Tags: firefox, troubleshooting, navigation

In Firefox 5, the menubar and sometimes even the right-click options do not render above the screen content, making them unselectable. They momentarily appear for a fraction of a second, but make the menu unusable.

On more than one machine I am experiencing this non-rendering issue. I have disabled almost every addon and reverted to the default theme. Has anyone else experienced this issue and fixed it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going to `Firefox bar` > `Options` > `Advanced` > `General` and unchecking the `Use hardware acceleration when available` should fix it.

[image]
[image]

[Reference](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/questions/764278#answer-116705).

Comment: Wonderful....it actually makes firefox usable again, for me. Thank you

Comment: Glad it helped :).